# How can I define font size in Marco.h base on device size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, font-size

I would like to define label font size base on device size. Here is what I done so far but does not work.

**Macros.h**

```
#define ScreenH [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
#define ScreenW [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width

//Weakself
#define WEAKSELF __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

//Screen
#define iphone5 (ScreenH == 568)     // Width = 320  [iphone5 | iphone5S | iphoneSE]
#define iphone6 (ScreenH == 667)     // Width = 375  [iphone6 | iphone6S | iphone7 | iphone8]
#define iphone6p (ScreenH == 736)    // Width = 414  [iphone6P | iphone6SP | iphone7P]
#define iphoneX (ScreenH == 812)     // Width = 375  [iphoneX]
#define ipadAir2 (ScreenH == 1024)   // Width = 768  [ipad(5G) | ipadAir | ipadAir2 | iPadPro(9.7)]
#define ipadPro105 (ScreenH == 1112) // Width = 834  [iPadPro(10.5)]
#define iPadPro129 (ScreenH == 1366) // Width = 1024 [iPadPro(12.9) | iPadPro(12.9 2G)]

//Font
#define PFR [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0 ? @"FiraSans-Regular" : @"FiraSans-Regular"
#define PFR20Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:20];
#define PFR18Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:18];
#define PFR16Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:16];
#define PFR15Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:15];
#define PFR14Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:14];
#define PFR13Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:13];
#define PFR12Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:12];
#define PFR11Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:11];
#define PFR10Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:10];

#define TittleFont  (ScreenH == 568) ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:11] : (ScreenH == 667)  ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:12] : (ScreenH == 736) ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:12] : (ScreenH == 812) ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:12] : (ScreenH == 1024) ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:14] : (ScreenH == 1112) ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:16] : (ScreenH == 1366) ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:16];
```

**ViewController.m**

```
_lblMerchantName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
_lblMerchantName.font = TittleFont;  //Here will hit error "Expected expression"
[self addSubview:_lblMerchantName];
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the code where you defined `ScreenH` and `PFR`?

Comment: @trungduc edited with ScreenH and PFR define

Comment: I only see `#define ScreenW` but can't see `#define ScreenH` anywhere. Are you sure you defined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you defined `ScreenH` in your question, i will assume you defined it as

```
#define ScreenH [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

There are some problems in your code.

- I think it should be `TitleFont` instead of `TittleFont` :)
- As I see, you defined `#define iphone5 (ScreenH == 568)` so when you define `TittleFont`, let use `iphone5` instead of `(ScreenH == 568)`, same with another case
- Don't need to use `;` at the end of `TitleFont` define
- You forgot to give `TitleFont` a default font (in else statement).

Try my code below, it worked.

```
#define ScreenH [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height

//Weakself
#define WEAKSELF __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

//Screen
#define iphone5 (ScreenH == 568)     // Width = 320  [iphone5 | iphone5S | iphoneSE]
#define iphone6 (ScreenH == 667)     // Width = 375  [iphone6 | iphone6S | iphone7 | iphone8]
#define iphone6p (ScreenH == 736)    // Width = 414  [iphone6P | iphone6SP | iphone7P]
#define iphoneX (ScreenH == 812)     // Width = 375  [iphoneX]
#define ipadAir2 (ScreenH == 1024)   // Width = 768  [ipad(5G) | ipadAir | ipadAir2 | iPadPro(9.7)]
#define ipadPro105 (ScreenH == 1112) // Width = 834  [iPadPro(10.5)]
#define iPadPro129 (ScreenH == 1366) // Width = 1024 [iPadPro(12.9) | iPadPro(12.9 2G)]

//Font
#define PFR [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0 ? @"FiraSans-Regular" : @"FiraSans-Regular"
#define PFR20Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:20];
#define PFR18Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:18];
#define PFR16Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:16];
#define PFR15Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:15];
#define PFR14Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:14];
#define PFR13Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:13];
#define PFR12Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:12];
#define PFR11Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:11];
#define PFR10Font [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:10];

#define kDefaultTitleFont [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:16]

#define TittleFont  iphone5 ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:11] : iphone6  ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:12] : iphone6p ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:12] : iphoneX ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:12] : ipadAir2 ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:14] : ipadPro105 ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:16] : iPadPro129 ? [UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:16] : kDefaultTitleFont
```

Comment: Is this a good time to suggest maybe a UIFont category would be better suited?  Then you make a method titleFont which you can use for anywhere.  It reduces the overall application size by removing the code duplications inserted everywhere by that macro. [UIFont titleFont]; done.

Comment: @ekscrypto Actually, category (you said extension) is always better than macro in this case. But it's up to OP. Maybe he has some reasons to use macro instead of category :)

Comment: maybe you can use PFR11Font, PFR12Font.... instead of "[UIFont fontWithName:PFR size:11]" if you already added that in your code...just a suggestion.